# earlier/before/ago, which to choose?

Tags: word-choice

I found a note in Collins dictionary:

> You only use ago when you are talking about a period of time measured back from the present. If you are talking about a period measured back from some earlier time, you use before or previously.

However, here are choices that all sound right to me.

> A month **earlier/before/ago**, our relationship ended. Our
> relationship ended a month **earlier/before/ago**.   (I intend to mean
> a month before now. I think the sentence order does not significantly
> affect the word choice here.)
>
> He had died a month **before/earlier/ago**. He died a month **ago**.  (I
> intend to mean a month measured back from the present. I think the
> tense does not significantly affect the word choice here.)
>
> She had rented the flat some fourteen months
> **previously/before/earlier**.
>
> When I make appointments, I will think obsessively about the
> appointments several hours **previously/before/earlier**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to express this is:

ago is always used in relation to the present time.

He left six months ago. [in relation to today]

He left six months earlier. [in relation to some time in the past]. This works for earlier, before and previously [with an action verb].

You often see in movies, a mistake. The scriptwriters signal a time and use:

**Six months ago**, in the narration, when they mean **six months earlier**.

Comment: You never mentioned *He left six months **before***. Personally, I feel that the "before" version is a better fit for Past **Perfect** usage, so *He **had** left six month before* sounds just a bit more natural than *He **had** left six month **earlier***. But I completely agree that ***ago*** is normally relative to ***now***, not "current narrative reference time".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Everything except ago functions in the past.

Comment: Unquestionably, *I moved here six months **ago*** is always always relative to ***now***, and *I moved here six months **before / earlier*** (and perhaps ***previous*** in some contexts, not necessarily this *exact* example) is always relative to some pre-established "reference time" in the past. But I'm inclined to say *I moved here/there six months **back*** could be ***either***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Every single question on this site could be changed, revised, rewritten etc. The term back was not the question.

Comment: Don't you ever get tired of your negativity?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I covered everything by explaining how ago works versus the others.  The others are never in relation to the present time. Ago is always. And back was not part of the question. But back is like ago. It is in relation to the present time.